# How to pre-select rows in Shiny DT datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, datatable, shiny

I'm using Shiny (0.12.0) with DT (0.0.65) for row-selections in this [Shiny datatable](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-rows/). I want to pre-select the first 5 rows. I have tried:

- Changing the class of row using `callback` JS in datatable. However, that is not reflecting in the `input$x1_rows_selected` variable. Only the background/highlight changes because of CSS.
- Using `.click()` in either `rowCallback` in the options list or in `callback`. This does not work either when loading the page. However, it works (updates `input$x1_rows_selected`) when I run the same code through the console / browser dev tool.

`callback` JS:

```
output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(cars,
        rows = $("#x1 tbody tr");
        $(rows).slice(0,5).each(function() {
            $(this).click();
        });
    )
})
```

Comment: Just for the record, same issue posted at https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/89 and mentioned in https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/93 I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Although for client-side, I had to do:
`selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = as.character(c(1,3,8))`
rather than just numeric.

If you can post your comment as answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This feature has been added to **DT** (>= 0.1.3). Examples:

```
library(shiny)
if (packageVersion('DT') < '0.1.3') devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      h1('Client-side processing'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('x1'),
      h1('Server-side processing'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('x2')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, server = FALSE,
      selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = c(1, 3, 8, 12))
    )
    output$x2 = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, server = TRUE,
      selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = rownames(iris)[c(1, 3, 8, 12)])
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Hi! Could you explain a bit a difference between client-side and server-side precessing? How does it influence anything?

Comment: @ClaudH Here is the documentation: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/server.html

Comment: is it possible to bind a reactive input to the selected argument? I tried but not working `selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = input$s)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a reactive to the selected input, here's a quick example of how that might be done.

I've modified the client side example above to add a `selectInput` that allows you to dynamically choose which row to highlight.  It would be trivial to extend this to a multi-select scenario.

```
library(shiny)
if (packageVersion('DT') < '0.1.3') devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      shiny::selectInput("myrow", "Select Row", choices = seq(nrow(iris))),
      h1('Client-side processing'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('x1'),
      h1('Server-side processing'),
      DT::dataTableOutput('x2')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    myselected <- shiny::reactive(as.integer(input$myrow))

    output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, server = FALSE,
      selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = myselected())
    )
    output$x2 = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, server = TRUE,
      selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = rownames(iris)[c(1, 3, 8, 12)])
    )
  }
)
```