# Pre-select rows of a dynamic DT in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

This question is the more dynamic version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746325/how-to-pre-select-rows-in-shiny-dt-datatables).

I have a DT in shiny app that could be empty at initialization. I'd like to pre-select all rows in DT. My first try is like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      radioButtons("select", "", c("none", "iris")),
      DT::dataTableOutput('x1')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive({
      if (input$select == "none") {
        return(NULL)
      } else if (input$select == "iris"){
        return(iris)
      }
    })
    output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(
      data(), server = FALSE,
      selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = seq_len(nrow(data())))
    )
  }
)
```

It did selection right but there is an error of `Warning: Error in seq_len: argument must be coercible to non-negative integer` in the beginning. I think that's because `seq_len` cannot take an `NULL` input. Interestingly after the initialization, switching back and forth doesn't generate new errors.

I tried this version to use an reactive value for rows vector, with empty result for empty input:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      radioButtons("select", "", c("none", "iris")),
      DT::dataTableOutput('x1')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive({
      if (input$select == "none") {
        return(NULL)
      } else if (input$select == "iris"){
        return(iris)
      }
    })
    all_rows <- reactive({
      df <- data()
      if (is.null(df)) {
        return(seq_len(0))
      } else {
        return(seq_len(nrow(df)))
      }
    })
    output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(
      data(), server = FALSE,
      selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = all_rows()))
  }
)
```

However this doesn't work. I tried another version which used a modified `seq_len` but it also doesn't work.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
seq_len_null_check <- function(len){
  if (is.null(len)){
    return(integer(0))
  } else {
    return(seq_len(len))
  }
}
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      radioButtons("select", "", c("none", "iris")),
      DT::dataTableOutput('x1')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactive({
      if (input$select == "none") {
        return(NULL)
      } else if (input$select == "iris"){
        return(iris)
      }
    })
    output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(
      data(), server = FALSE,
      selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = seq_len_null_check(nrow(data())))
    )
  }
)
```

How can I remove the error in first version, or make the 2nd, 3rd version work?

Comment: I found using `validate` could remove the first error. However when I switched between two kind of data sources, the DT is always selected with row count of first table.  So when the data source changes DT updates but do not change preselection at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow reactive on selected evaluation, you need to call `datatable` from within `renderDataTable`:

```
output$x1 = renderDataTable(
              datatable( data(),
                         selection = list(mode = 'multiple', selected = all_rows())), 
              server = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved both the error problem and updating pre-selection by data problem.