# Dynamically pre-select row using DT in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I try to dynamically pre-select rows in shiny using DT and saw this question/answer: [Pre-select rows of a dynamic DT in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077184/pre-select-rows-of-a-dynamic-dt-in-shiny)
I do however need the 'native' appearance of DT with the intelligent column filters.

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
    ui=shinyUI(
        fixedPage(
            radioButtons('selectedRows',
                         'select a row',
                         c(
                         "row one"="1",
                         "row two"="2")),
            DT::dataTableOutput('myTable')
        )
    )
,

server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    selRows <- reactiveValues(row=c())

    observe({
        validate(need(input$selectedRows, message=FALSE)) 
        selRows$row <- as.numeric(input$selectedRows)
    })

    output$myTable <- DT::renderDataTable ({
                                             mtcars[,1:5]
                                          },server=T,
                                            rownames = T,
                                            filter = "top",
                                            selection = list(mode='multiple',
                                                             selected = selRows$row))

    })
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you say 'dynamically pre-select' do you just mean 'select from another input'? Or is this a question about initialising the table with a certain selection?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I mean 'select from another input', as in the example above from input$selectedRows. When I give selRows$row a fix value, e.g. 1 the table is correctly initialized with row 1 pre-selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is written in the other post to wrap it within `datatable()` then it works :)

```
output$myTable <- DT::renderDataTable ({
  datatable(
    mtcars[,1:5],
    rownames = T,
    filter = "top",
    selection = list(mode='multiple',
                     selected = selRows$row)  
  )
})
```