# R Shiny - Pre-selection of rows in Select extension for Datatables

Tags: r, shiny, dt

How can I pre-select rows with the Select extension for Datatables in Shiny? I've checked the documentation here: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/. But I can't figure it out. I tried specifying `rows = 1:3` but that didn't have any effect:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

dat <- iris[1:17,]

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DTOutput("table")),

  server = function(input, output, session) {  

    output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
        datatable(
          dat,
          options = list(select = list(
            style = "multi", 
            rows = 1:3, 
            selector = "td:not(.notselectable)")),
          extensions = "Select", selection = "none")
    }, server = FALSE)

  }
)
```

NB. I am using the Select extension for Datatables, not the DT package's implementation of row selection. So `selection = list(selected = 1:3)` will not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pre-select rows in Shiny DT datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746325/how-to-pre-select-rows-in-shiny-dt-datatables)

Comment: Hi Kevin, unfortunately not. I have had to turn off the package's implementation of row selection (see selection = 'none') in order to use the Select extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `select.rows` option. You can use a callback:

```
output[["table"]] <- renderDT({
  datatable(
    dat,
    callback = JS("table.rows([0,1,2]).select();"),
    options = list(select = list(
      style = "multi", 
      selector = "td:not(.notselectable)")),
    extensions = "Select", selection = "none")
}, server = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Stéphane. I am having difficulty combing this with the callback you had written for retrieving selected rows though. Would it please be possible to have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59024766/10841085?