# R Shiny - Select extension for DataTables - getting selected rows and preselecting rows

Tags: r, shiny, dt

The app below has a modal that displays a DT when opened. For the DT, row selection is enabled and I am using the Select extension for DataTables instead of the DT package's implementation of row selection.

The modal has two buttons `Apply` and `Cancel`.

1. When the user clicks `Apply`, the indices of any rows that they may
   have selected are stored in a reactive value `rv$selected_rows` via
   `rv$selected_rows = input$table_rows_selected` and the modal is
   dismissed.
2. When the user clicks `Cancel`, any changes that they have made to
   their selection are discarded by resetting
   `input$table_rows_selected` back to `rv$selected_rows`.

So say the user opens the modal, selects rows 1 and 2 and clicks `Apply`. If they open the modal again and add row 3 to their selection and then click `Cancel`, this change should be discarded so that when the modal is reopened, only rows 1 and 2 are selected.

I can reset the value of `input$table_rows_selected` to `rv$selected_cols` each time `Cancel` is clicked using `setInputValue` (see console for to see how the value changes when `Cancel` is clicked) but the DT does not rerender to reflect this change even though it is dependent on the value of `input$table_rows_selected`. I think this is due to the callback that retrieves the selected rows conflicting with the callback used to pre-select rows but can't be sure.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

get_set_rows <- function(idx = NULL) {

  cb = c(
    "var id = $(table.table().node()).closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
    "table.on('click', 'tbody', function(){",
    "  setTimeout(function(){",
    "    var indexes = table.rows({selected:true}).indexes();",
    "    var indices = Array(indexes.length);",
    "    for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i){",
    "      indices[i] = indexes[i] + 1;",
    "    }",
    "    Shiny.setInputValue(id + '_rows_selected', indices);",
    "  }, 0);",
    "});"
  )

  if(!is.null(idx)) {

    cb = c(cb, sprintf('table.rows([%s]).select();', paste(idx - 1, collapse = ','))) #Subtracting 1 since DT uses base indexing

  } else {

    cb = c(cb, 'table.rows().deselect();')

  }

  JS(cb)

}

setInputVal <- function(session, inputId, value) {
  session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'setInputVal', message = list(id = inputId, value = value))
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('setInputVal', function(data) {
  Shiny.setInputValue(data.id, data.value);
});")),
    actionButton('edit', 'Edit'), 
    bsModal(
      id = 'modal', title = 'Title', trigger = 'edit',
      DTOutput('table'),
      actionButton('apply', 'Apply'), 
      actionButton('cancel', 'Cancel')
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {  

    rv = reactiveValues(selected_rows =  NULL)

    output$table <- renderDT({

      datatable(
        iris,
        callback = get_set_rows(input$table_rows_selected),
        options = list(select = list(
          style = "multi", 
          selector = "td:not(.notselectable)")),
        extensions = "Select", selection = "none")

    }, server = FALSE)


    observeEvent(input$apply, {

      rv$selected_cols = input$table_rows_selected

      toggleModal(session, 'modal')

      print(paste('rv$selected_cols at Apply:', paste(rv$selected_cols, collapse = ', ')))

    })


    observeEvent(input$cancel, {

      setInputVal(session, 'table_rows_selected', rv$selected_cols)

      toggleModal(session, 'modal')
    })

    observe(print(paste('input$table_rows_selected:', paste(input$table_rows_selected, collapse = ', '))))

  }
)
```

Comment: This seems to work with `DT 0.8` but I'm not sure to understand the problem. What if you put `input$table_rows_selected` at the beginning of `renderDT` ?

Comment: Ah! I was on 0.6, it works perfectly in 0.10. Thank you so much @Stéphane. Basically, I would like to store the value of `input$table_rows_selected` in `rv$selected_cols` each time the user clicks Apply. If the user changes the row selection at any time after clicking `Apply` and then clicks `Cancel`, I would like to discard those changes by resetting the value of `input$table_rows_selected` back to `rv$selected_cols`. While I was able to reset the value, the change was not being reflected in the UI under the older version. I wonder why that was.

Comment: ...but when I try it in my actual app, it does not work consistently. Would you think `delay` would help here? I have tried using it in `renderDT` but cannot get it to work.