# Make datatable #DT rownames not clickable

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

I have a table made with the DT package where my cells are clickable. However, I would like to have the cells in the row names not clickable or in other word, specify a range of columns, something like  ‘selected = [2:5]’ where cells are actually active for a click base behavior.

Hope the problem is quiet enough visual. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the click for the selection ? The code below works for me but I'm not using the latest version of `DT`.

```
  output$dtable <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris, extensions = "Select", selection = "none",
              options = list(
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(className = "not-selectable", targets = 0)
                ),
                select = list(
                  style = "single",
                  selector = "td:not(.not-selectable)"
                )
              )
    )
  })
```

Comment: Thank you Stéphane, I’ll check that when I come back home and let you know about the behavior. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Hi Stéphane, the snippet works well, thanks. Can I add a cell preselection argument with the datatable 'Select' extension on the list ?

Comment: @SofianeM'barki See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58950403/1100107) for the preselection of rows. Please do not forget to accept the answer it it works.